# How to corrrect this error "scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@2adb58ad"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have ratings file in this format `1::654::5::7546786`. My file consists of `movieId`,`userId`,`rating`,`timestamp`. When reading the file, Exception appear.

```
scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@2adb58ad (of class [Ljava.lang.String;)
    at smallData$$anonfun$8.apply(smallData.scala:77)
    at smallData$$anonfun$8.apply(smallData.scala:77)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1334)
```

Exception give error in line 77

```
val user_mov = data_test_wo_header.map(_.split("::") match { case Array(user, mov) =>
(user.toInt,mov.toInt)
})
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Well you are expecting only two columns but you have four, so the match fails... isn't that pretty obvious?  You can do this: `case Array(user, mov, _ , _) =>` to match exactly four but ignore the last two. Or if you want to ignore any other columns  `case Array(user, mov, _ @ _*) =>` or turning the array into a list `_.split("::").toList match { case user :: mov :: _ =>`

Comment: Thanks for replying.When applying case Array(user, mov, _ , _) =>, giving the same error. In case of _.split("::").toList match { case user :: mov :: _ =>, this exception appear scala.MatchError: List(379,5418) (of class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)

Comment: That means that you got either an empty list or a list with only one element. So you have some malformed data, or maybe the `split` is wrong.

Comment: yes, I have error in split and it works.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. You already solved your problem or not?

Comment: Yes,my problem solved . thanks